# How to make a binding computed property update on an ObservableObject class?

Tags: swiftui

I have this class:

```
class MyModel:ObservableObject {
  
  var selectedObjectIndex:Int {
    set {}
    get {
      let selectedResult = objects.filter({ $0 == selectedObject })
      if selectedResult == 0 { return 0 }
      return objects.firstIndex(of: selectedResult.first!)!
    }
  }
}
```

This `selectedObjectIndex` would normally be a `@Published var selectedObjectIndex:Int` but because it is a computed property, I cannot use `@Published` there.

So I was forced to add this to the model

```
func getselectedObjectIndexBinding() -> Binding<Int> { 
  let binding = Binding<Int>(
    get: { () -> Int in
      return self.selectedObjectIndex
    }) { (newValue) in
    self.selectedObjectIndex = newValue
  }
  return binding
}
```

In the view I have a Picker, using this like

```
Picker(selection: myModel.getselectedObjectIndexBinding(),
       label: Text("select")) {
```

The picker appears correctly but If I set a new value on it, the model `selectedObjectIndex` is not updated.

Comment: Your set method for selectedObjectIndex does nothing

Comment: how do I solve that?

Comment: That depends on what do you want to be persistent (ie store) on `selectedObjectIndex.set`. From your code the intention is not clear - would you elaborate more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below, whenever a binding is updated, your `selectedObjectIndex` can trigger `ObjectWillChange` notification after doing some relevant work. I have created `selectedObjectIndex` as `propertyObserver`.

```
struct CreditCardFront: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var myModel:MyModel
   
   
    var body: some View {
        
        Picker(selection: myModel.getselectedObjectIndexBinding(),
               label: Text("select")) {
            
            ForEach(1..<10) { value in
                Text("\(value)")
            }
        }
        Text("\(myModel.selectedObjectIndex ?? 0)")
        
    }
    
    
}

class MyModel:ObservableObject {
    
    var selectedObjectIndex:Int?{
        didSet{
            // Your work here
            update() // call notification on specific change
        }
    }
    
    func getselectedObjectIndexBinding() -> Binding<Int> {
        let binding = Binding<Int>(
            get: { () -> Int in
                return self.selectedObjectIndex ?? 0
            }) { (newValue) in
            self.selectedObjectIndex = newValue
        }
        return binding
    }
    
    func update(){
        self.objectWillChange.send()
    }
}
```

**@main-:**

```
@main
struct WaveViewApp: App {
    @StateObject var model:MyModel
    init() {
        let model = MyModel()
        _model = StateObject(wrappedValue: model)
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            CreditCardFront(myModel: model)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just `@StateObject var model = MyModel()`?

Comment: @pawello2222 we could definitely do that, but I had a old code snippet written that way which I just modified.